# IIS marking worker process unhealthy

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8, was7

I am using windows 2012, .net 4.5. I have a web application that can occasionally do heavy processing and keep the server tied down for some time (~ 8-10 minutes).

I am seeing randomly that WAS is killing the worker process since it fails to respond to its pings in timely fashion.

So i set the pingEnabled property of App Pool to false, since i thought WAS wasn't going to ping worker process and hence not kill it.

But i can see that its still killing the worker process and marking it unhealthy. Is there a way i can configure it to not ping it, I am trying to stay away from any random increases in ping timeouts etc

Answer (score -2):

You could try using the new QueueBackgroundWorkItem Method.

This was created to process long running jobs that are spawned from within ASP.net.

> QBWI schedules a task which can run in the background, independent of
>   any request. This differs from a normal ThreadPool work item in that
>   ASP.NET automatically keeps track of how many work items registered
>   through this API are currently running, and the ASP.NET runtime will
>   try to delay AppDomain shutdown until these work items have finished
>   executing.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx

I believe this requires asp.net 4.5.2 so you might need to upgrade to get this functionality.

Comment: Can you add detail from the link?  Links do break and that renders the answer here less useful/useless